# How do I get the current spreadsheet name and NOT sheet name in google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheets()
    .forEach(function (s, i) {
        if (i === 0) s.getRange('D1').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName());
        s.getRange('D2')
            .setValue(s.getName())
    })
}
```

The above script only gives me the sheet name NOT the entire spreadsheet name.
How do I get it to place the filename in this instance?

In other words, I have a pic below:

[Difference between Spreadsheet name and sheet name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIVzF.png)

Answer (score 5):

To get the name of the Spreadsheet, not Sheets try:

```
function myFunction() {
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName()
Logger.log(name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function GetWorkbookName() {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).